# (Batch) How to get text inside href=""?

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

I have a htm file with `href="example.com/page"` somewhere on its source code, how could i get the link between the " "?

So far I have tried modifying this piece of code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "str="
set "string=stuff href="example.com/page"end morestuff"

set string=!string:href=^
!
set string=!string:end=^

!
FOR /F skip^=1eol^= %%S in ("!string!") do if NOT DEFINED str set "str=%%S"
echo(!str!
pause > nul
```

However on line 6 it appears that changing **href** to **href="** breaks the code, and changing **end** to **"** also breaks something, would like to know if it is possible to fix this or if there is an alternative for this?

Comment: You cannot have an equal-to sign in the search string of a sub-string substitution expression, since the `=` separates search and replace strings; I would use `href` as the search string first and when having removed it (by `set "string=!string:*=href=!"`), I would use sub-string expansion to remove the `=` as well, like `if "!string:~,1!"=="=" set "string=!string:~1!"`; then you could specify the `"` as a delimiter for `for /F`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just want the `example.com/page` part:

```
@echo off
set "string=stuff href="example.com/page"end morestuff"
for /f tokens^=2delims^="" %%a in ("%string%") do set "substr=%%a"
echo %substr%
```

Reading from file as per comment:

```
@echo off
set "file=file.txt"
for /f tokens^=2delims^="" %%a in ('findstr /IRC:"href=" "%file%"') do set "substr=%%a"
echo %substr%
```

Seeing that you require reading from an html file, I would recommend using something a little more robust, like `powershell`.

Create a file with `.ps1` extension, paste the content, make sure you put the path and filename of you file in `$file_path` replacing `file.txt`:

```
$file_path = 'file.txt'
$rgx = '(?<=href\=").*?(?=">)'
select-string -Path $file_path -Pattern $rgx -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

now you can either run it from `cmd`:

```
powershell -File test_url.ps1
```

Or simply open powershell cli and run directly from there:

```
.\test_url.ps1
```

Comment: The actual file i am searching have more quotes, is it possible to set `href="` as a prefix?

Comment: ok, you never mentioned a file, you used a variable. So would you want to search a file for `href=` and only then print the url?

Comment: yes, pretty much, i the reason for that is that the file (HTML) being searched has each line being searched separatedly and there are more "" (quotes) but there is only one 'href="' each line.

Comment: that seems to output whatever is in the first occasion of " " for example whenever this line is being read: `<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="example.com/page">0ad9fabf-a3da-4279-9..&gt;</a></td><td align="right">2020-04-24 12:39  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>`
it outputs "top" instead of "example.com/page"...?

Comment: alright I'll wait, though what does 2delims mean exactly?

Comment: it is not `2delims` it is `tokens=2` there is just no space between `tokens=2 delims=` because of the fact that we did not use double quotes, anyway, pelase see update. I recommend the powershell script as it will be more robust than `batch`

Comment: currently even though powershell script is most efficient I am required to use batch (for other reasons) any idea on how to fix `set "file=file.txt"
for /f tokens^=2delims^="" %%a in ('findstr /IRC:"href=" "%file%"') do set "substr=%%a"` outputting "top" Instead of the link? Is it possible to set `href="` as a prefix and the closest `"` as a suffix? (to get the text between them)

Comment: @BigCore if you can state the reasons? The thing is batch is not meant to work with all these special characters. We call them poison characters because they break batch files properly. so we have to really hack a lot of code together to make it work, but it might still not work on the next file. So please state the actual reason you need batch and not powershell.